# web2py makes no http connection, how does it communicate with browsers

Tags: security, http, web2py

I was trying to sniff HTTP packets though wireshark on my localhost, when i tried working on a web2py instance at my localhost no http connections found. While digging deeper into it i found it is not creating `any connections in the application layer. well then how does it communicate with browsers without http? (I have heard of web2py as a very secure framework, now this thing is creating more curiosity in me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's not an HTTP connection on port 8000 (which is the IANA registered port for irdmi)? If you use wireshark, you can choose to decode as HTTP when the port isn't the standard port for the protocol.

Comment: ohh! cool! that is where i am getting wrong.. yeah! i gonna change the port, but still what is irdmi?

Comment: Could be "Intel Remote Desktop Management Interface"? It's registered with an `@intel.com` address: http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers

Comment: Okay! i have changed the port. 38490, irdmi is gone. but still it not showing me http anywhere!

Comment: In Wireshark, right-click on the packets (at least one of them for a given TCP connection), choose "Decode as...", then "Transport" tab and "HTTP".

Comment: ohh! wow! now i can see http request headers. Now the question is, what exactly is happening here?